# PHP set date to end at a specific hour

Tags: php, date

I am currently working at a system for a manufacturing company that monitors a daily output data, but the company follows a 24hours production duration which the date ends at `6:00 AM`, but the standard `PHP` date/time change after 12:00 midnight,is it possible to change the `PHP` date/timestamp to change the current date after 6am?

### Edit

this is what i have so far, so the date must be todays date.

```
  <?php

  $dt = new DateTime("2017-07-07 00:00:00", 
  new DateTimeZone("Asia/Tokyo"));
  echo "Start: ", $dt->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"), PHP_EOL;
  $dt->add(new DateInterval("PT6H"));
  echo "<br/>";
  echo "End:   ", $dt->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"), PHP_EOL;

  ?>
```

The output is below

```
   Start: 2017-07-07 00:00:00
   End: 2017-07-07 06:00:00
```

What i want to achieve is the logic below, the day will start at 6:00 AM in the morning then will end on 5:59 AM on the next day.

```
   Start: 2017-07-07 06:00:00 AM
   End: 2017-07-07 05:59:00 AM
```

Comment: What if you just added 6 hours to `date()`'s result via `date_modify()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't fundamentally change the way the Calendar works.  It seems to me that what you are looking for is a pair of DateTime(s) that represent one shift.  As you described them it's pretty clear.  I'll just use an array to keep them together:

```
$shift = array();
$format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

$shift['start'] = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, date('Y-m-d') . ' 6:00:00', new DateTimeZone("Asia/Tokyo"));
$shift['end'] = clone $shift['start'];
// Now add 23:59:59 to it
$shift['end']->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 Day - 1 seconds'));

echo "Start: ", $shift['start']->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"), PHP_EOL;
echo "End: ", $shift['end']->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"), PHP_EOL;
echo PHP_EOL;

var_dump($shift);
```

Here's a sample:  https://3v4l.org/m1XgX

Comment: In general to do date ranges, you need a start and end.  I have worked on a lot of scheduling applications that involve date/time windows (from - to) and you will need a pair.  The advantage here is that you don't lose your start object and have each of them separate.